# Слияние ключей в массиве - PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Возможно ли в массиве ключи объединить, если в том или ином ключе идет содержание из одного или двух символов то объединился со следующим.

Массив такой

```
array ( 0 => 'В', 1 => 'городе', 2 => 'весна', );
```

А вот как сделать так понять никак не могу.

```
array ( 0 => 'В городе',  1=> 'весна', );
```

Comment: Можно, перебирать массив и создавать новый.

Comment: А если `[0 => 'А', 1 => 'в', 2 => 'городе', 3 => 'весна']`, тогда как должно получиться?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov или `А, и ,в,  городе, уже, весна`

Answer (score 3):

Например, как-нибудь так:

```
$a = array ( 0 => 'В', 1 => 'городе', 2 => 'весна', );
$tmp = null;
$b = array_reduce($a, function($res, $el) use (&$tmp) {
    if ($tmp) {$el = "$tmp $el"; $tmp = null;}
    if (strlen($el)<=2) $tmp = $el;
    else $res[] = $el;
    return $res;
}, array());
if ($tmp) {$b[] = $tmp;} // иначе можно потерять последний короткий элемент...
var_export($b); // array (0 => 'В городе', 1 => 'весна',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант:

```
$input = ['И', 'в', 'городе', 'снова', 'весна', 'но'];
$output = [];

array_map(function($item)use(&$output){
    static $temp;
    if (mb_strlen($item) < 3) {
        $temp .= $item . ' ';
    } elseif (isset($temp)) {
        $output[] = $temp . $item;
        $temp = null;
    } else {
        $output[] = $item;
    }
}, $input);

var_dump($output);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'И в городе' (length=18)
  1 => string 'снова' (length=10)
  2 => string 'весна' (length=10)
```

Т.е., если последние элементы массива объединять не с чем, то они отбрасываются.